# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate from 13.0.3 to 13.1.1 without losing current settings

Tags: intellij-idea, upgrade

I use IntellJ IDEA Ultimate Edition on Windows 7 machine.

I would like to upgrade from **version 13.0.3 to 13.1.1** in a way that will keep all my existing settings and plugin setup.

Currently it's installed in **JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.2** directory.  Installation wizard gives an option to uninstall the existing version (that is not checked by default) and then suggests installing it into **13.1.1** directory.

What is the right way to install it *as upgrade*, so I do not lose anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not lose any settings by uninstalling. 
The settings is in `C:\Users\xxx\.IntelliJIdea13`

Comment: Found the directory.  Thank you.

Comment: One more question. Where does it store the current project, its list of modules, and status (like, excluded) of directories inside?

Comment: In the project's directory. ".idea" folder